# C++ build application with newer compiler without rebuilding the libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I have a C++ program that uses several libraries.
I build my application and the libraries with gcc version 4.
The libraries are built as static libraries and the header and libX.a files are added to the project.
Can I build my application with a newer gcc (for example gcc 7) without needing to rebuild also the libraries?
If I try building with the newer gcc and succeed, does it means I won't get any unexpected problems related to this later?

Comment: You should definitely rebuild everything if you are going to jump over 3 major versions of compiler.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you should recompile everything when doing such a major compiler upgrade.

Successful linking does not guarantee you will not get problems at runtime. This is due to ABI incompatibility between GCC versions. You might get lucky but it's something you can't depend on in the long run.

You might try to use [GCC's code generation switches](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code%20Gen%20Options) to make your compiled file compatible with your old libraries by looking up what has changed since those libraries were compiled in [GCC's ABI policy](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) but I think it's just not worth the effort.